# What are pros and cons for using Virtual Machines to manage desktops?

Tags: virtual-machines, desktop-management

VMs are great for many development tasks but can you use them to 'manage' desktops? I'm thinking of setting up some systems so that they can only execute a VM at startup. This seems like a good way to control desktops and keep them running clean. Is this true in practice or does it just add a layer of maintenance on top of the underlying OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think having everyone run a standard image sounds good in the beginning but it doesn't really buy you any more than installing from a standard image.   Using a product like ghost seems like it would do just as much for you with out the added hassle of managing a VM environment on every machine

Answer (score 1):

I think there's a big advantage in that you can have a standard image that's hardware-independent.

Answer (score 1):

VM desktops are great for uncommonly used workstations.  In our QA environment, the testers can utilize VMs each with different OS/software combinations.  This is much simpler than maintaining a room full of physical desktops.  You also have the added capability of snapshotting before installing new software to test.